# Difference between importing module and passing it as a prop vs importing it from within the module that actually uses it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider this first approach. It imports `SomeMassiveModule` in the `Parent` component and then passes it down to the `Child` components.

```
// Parent.js
import React from 'react'
import * as SomeMassiveModule from 'some-massive-module'

export default function Parent() {
    return (
        <Child SomeMassiveModule={SomeMassiveModule} />
        <Child SomeMassiveModule={SomeMassiveModule} />
        <Child SomeMassiveModule={SomeMassiveModule} />
    )
}
```

```
// Child.js
import React from 'react'

export default function Child({ SomeMassiveModule }) {
    return (
        <div>
            {SomeMassiveModule.SomeComponent}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Now, consider this second approach, which imports `SomeMassiveModule` in the `Child` component and then uses it.

```
// Parent.js
import React from 'react'

export default function Parent() {
    return (
        <Child />
        <Child />
        <Child />
    )
}
```

```
// Child.js
import React from 'react'
import * as SomeMassiveModule from 'some-massive-module'

export default function Child() {
    return (
        <div>
            {SomeMassiveModule.SomeComponent}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Is there a difference in performance between these two approaches? Does the bundling now happen three times in the second approach instead of just the once?

Comment: *"Does the bundling now happen three times in the second approach instead of just the once?"* Bundling is only concerned with files/modules, not with how often a module export is referenced.

Comment: So what you're saying is that there's no difference between these two approaches?

Comment: There is no difference with respect to bundling.

Comment: How about performance? That's what I'm wondering about. Is it better to pass down `SomeMassiveModule` to `Child` or I can just import it in `Child`?

Comment: You can only know if you actually measure performance. But even if there is a performance difference, it will be negligible compared to whatever else is going on in your app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the first approach when you want to pass different values in the props to the Child component. If it is going to be the constant (won't change in future) `import` option i.e 2nd approach seems better than the first one.